# Logging and getting the response in a controller

Tags: php, symfony2

I have an action that does two things:

1. It sends a chain of commands, and gets the response from an external API that we call `wrapper`.
2. It logs the chain of commands and the tunnel (look at tunnels as different machines) the command was sent to.

My problem is the contents of the `if` statement. The two things (sending the command/getting the response, and logging the exchange) are happening in that `if` block, and they both need the `chain` and `tunnel` variables. I'd ideally want to have two functions, `getResponseFromWrapper()` and `logCommandAndResponse()`, effectively reducing the number of statements inside my `if` block to just two.

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $response = '';
    $form = $this->createForm(new TerminalType());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $tunnel = $data['tunnel'];
        $chain = $data['chain'];

        $response = $this->retrieveResponseFromWrapper($chain, $tunnel);
        $this->get('command_logger')->log($chain, $tunnel, $response);
    }

    return $this->render('terminal/index.html.twig', [
        'title' => 'Terminal',
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'response' => $response
    ]);
}
```

In other words, I feel like the three first lines in the `if` block are making it a bit more difficult for the reader to know what's happening.

Better code might be:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $response = '';
    $form = $this->createForm(new TerminalType());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        list($chain, $tunnel) = $this->extractChainAndTunnelFromForm($form);
        $response = $this->retrieveResponseFromWrapper($chain, $tunnel);
        $this->get('command_logger')->log($chain, $tunnel, $response);
    }

    return $this->render('terminal/index.html.twig', [
        'title' => 'Terminal',
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'response' => $response
    ]);
}
```

This is much shorter. However, returning two values from a function leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

How can I improve the first code block and reduce the number of statements in the `if` block? Do I need to create something like a `DTO` (i.e. have my `extractCommandAndTunnelFromForm()` create a plain old PHP object and set the `tunnel` and `chain` as its properties)? Do I need to inject the `commandLogger` service into the service that sends commands to the `wrapper`, and remove logging from the controller entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the first code is **perfectly** fine in matter of conciseness and readability. You're being a lil bit obsessive, but it's not perfect in matter of  design.

Second, if I really had to do so to just improve the readability, I would refactor `retrieveResponseFromWrapper()` to accept a, let's say, `WrapperRequest` instance. On the other hand, I would refactor `extractChainAndTunnelFromForm()` to a `createWrapperRequestFromForm()` which obviously returns a `WrapperRequest` instance after its own internal processing of form data:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $request  = $this->createWrapperRequestFromForm($form);
    $response = $this->retrieveResponseFromWrapper($request);

    // If you wanna go shorter for the sake of sanity:  
    //
    // $response = $this->retrieveResponseFromWrapper(
    //     $request = $this->createWrapperRequestFromForm($form)
    // );

    // I also recommend to move this out, controllers just log access things
    $this->get('command_logger')
         ->log($request->getChain(), $request->getTunnel(), $response);
}
```

Now that I wrote it, you see, it's shorter and more unreadable! IMO shorter code and minimal number of methods are not *necessarily* an indication of more concise and readable code. The number of statements in a `if` block is not an effective factor to measure readability.

I remember when I was trying to find one-liners for every damn single thing I wrote. I went insane and even swapped `if`s with equivalent `AND`/`OR` statements. It was of course a pleasure but I've learnt to embrace simplicity and verbosity in order to be more readable for others.

Back to the design thing; The above code is a better code, not because it's shorter or it has just one return value, but because it separates your domain logic apart from the controller and it avoids **implementation leaks**. This controller does not know about `$tunnel` and `$chain`, it just transports them as blackbox data. That's why we often need **Data Validation** components separated from the controller and the Form Validation component.

I think that would be a better idea to refactor our controllers as just a **Transport Layer** around HTTP instead of such minor improvements. To pursue this I always think that my app needs be fully functional when the data is fed through terminal instead of HTTP, without regular forms.

To conclude; A reader must always tend to read the code in Service/Repo/Model/... classes in order to understand the business logic. Reading the controller code of a well-designed application must be boring cause it's just the means not the thing!

Comment: I agree with you on all points. I'm not a fond of one-liners, but the reason I was referring to line counts is that they are usually a good indication of code smell. So, just to make sure I'm getting what you mean, what you're suggesting is a domain transfer object; a plain old PHP object that holds `tunnel` and `chain` inside it, bundling them up into one object. Is that right?

Comment: I noticed you have also agreed to my second question that asks if I need to move logging outside the controller entirely. So, both of my questions (the use of a DTO and moving the logging process outside of the controller) should be done. Right?

Comment: Ideally yes.​​​